# Excel how to make checkerboard table range with conditional format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a checkerboard-style table format for excel using conditional formatting.
Aside from just formatting the cells manually, I am trying to use either a table format or a conditional format. My idea is to use the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions to determine which ones to format.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to use those functions in a conditional formula such as:   `=ISEVEN(SUM(ROW(tblTest[@]),COLUMN(tblTest[Column 1])))`

So, I ran an experiment with a named range of data like so:
[image]
...where each cell contains the formula: `=SUM(ROW(tblTest[@]),COLUMN([1]))`
The values, as you can see, are odd and even, and while they don't match the ROW and COLUMN values that I would expect for `tblTest` they do match the sum of the row and column of the workbook.

2nd part of the experiment is to set up the conditional formatting using the formula: `=ISEVEN(U2)` where U2 is the top-left cell of the range.  As you can see in the screenshot aboe though, the formatted cells are *all over the place* in their interpretation of ODD and EVEN.

My question is two-fold:

1. Can I create a checkerboard like format for a range?
2. Can I do it with conditional formatting?

In case you're wondering, the purpose of the conditional formatting would be to allow me to change the size of the range and the formatting without a lot of copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this amendment for your formula in the conditional formatting:

> =ISEVEN(SUM(ROW(),COLUMN()))